# Android: using gyroscope to change layout landscape and portrait

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have been set a project for college that needs to make use of the Android Gyroscope Functionality, the problem  is, my application is quite simple in that it just displays information about a sports event to the user (e.g. current games, stadium info, team stats etc).

I initially thought that I could make use of the Gyroscope to change my layout to a different style depending on the orientation of the screen (portrait and landscape) but from what I know now, it seems that this isn't really something that the Gyroscope is used for? correct me if i'm wrong?

My question is, what could I use the gyroscope for for a simple like I mentioned?

Comment: What about [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-gyro) ?

Answer (score 0):

Android already handles portrait and landscape orientation so as you mentioned there is no need to use gyroscope for this. I believe its the most popular usage is for a game controller when you should rotate your device to do something.

But sure you can use it for something similar in your app. Like to display an image always horizontally despite of the device rotation.